# TypeError trying to merge dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

While merging two dataframes:

```
result=pd.merge(data,df7.style.format(make_clickable),left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, 
  a <class 'pandas.io.formats.style.Styler'> was passed
```

Comment: because you've got `.style.format` associated with your second df: `df7.style.format(make_clickable)`. Try just merging on df7

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just go with

```
result = pd.merge(data, df7, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: The code is running but the text are not in hyperlink format..